# SQL select all values with both x any y elements

Tags: sql

How do I select all values that have both an element x and y from a different table. 
Lets say that I want to select all games that have an action and strategic genre. In one game table I have gameid, gametitle, in the other gamegenre I have gameid,gamegenre. I connect them together by gameid.

```
SELECT g.gameid, gg.genre
FROM games g
NATURAL JOIN gamegenre gg
WHERE gg.genre = 'Action' 
And gg.genre = 'Strategy';
```

Why does'nt this code select only games with genre Action and Strategy? And how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, forget `natural join`.  It is an abomination because it does not use properly declared foreign key relationships.  It simply uses columns that have the same name (and useless for tables that I create because almost all my tables have `CreatedAt` and `CreatedBy` columns).  Using unspecific names is dangerous; when something goes wrong, you it is not obvious.  List the columns used for the `join` using either `on` or `using`.

Second, your query will filter out all rows because `genre` cannot have two values at the same time.

Third, you can do what you want with `group by` and `having`.  Assuming no duplicates:

```
SELECT gameid
FROM games g INNER JOIN
     gamegenre gg
     ON (gameid)
WHERE gg.genre IN ('Action', 'Strategy')
GROUP BY gameid
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

Comment: Ow ok thank you very much! Yeah I use INNER JOIN in most cases just got a little lazy here :D